# xarray.open_dataset(): Trying to open .nc but I get 'double free or corruption error'

Tags: python, netcdf, python-xarray, netcdf4

I'm trying to read .nc files using the xarray function open_dataset, but when it tries I get this error:

Code:

```
import xarray as xr
xr.open_dataset('period1_7-74_mascara-landsat_7_-74_(2014-01-012014-12-31)_output.nc', engine='netcdf4')
```

Error

```
*** Error in `python': double free or corruption (!prev): 0x0000557e9de69e80 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x777e5)[0x7f2d5338b7e5]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x8037a)[0x7f2d5339437a]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(cfree+0x4c)[0x7f2d5339853c]
/home/cubo/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/netCDF4/_netCDF4.so(+0x20d66)[0x7f2d3c510d66]
/home/cubo/anaconda2/bin/../lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x774c)[0x7f2d540ed6fc]
/home/cubo/anaconda2/bin/../lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalCodeEx+0x7e9)[0x7f2d540ef4e9]
/home/cubo/anaconda2/bin/../lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(+0x6d377)[0x7f2d54078377]
/home/cubo/anaconda2/bin/../lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyObject_Call+0x43)[0x7f2d540537a3]
/home/cubo/anaconda2/bin/../lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(+0x5763d)[0x7f2d5406263d]
/home/cubo/anaconda2/bin/../lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyObject_Call+0x43)[0x7f2d540537a3]
/home/cubo/anaconda2/bin/../lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(+0xa1584)[0x7f2d540ac584]
/home/cubo/anaconda2/bin/../lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(+0x9de3b)[0x7f2d540a8e3b]
/home/cubo/anaconda2/bin/../lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyObject_Call+0x43)[0x7f2d540537a3]
/home/cubo/anaconda2/bin/../lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x3bb9)[0x7f2d540e9b69]
/home/cubo/anaconda2/bin/../lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalCodeEx+0x7e9)[0x7f2d540ef4e9]
/home/cubo/anaconda2/bin/../lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x6a08)[0x7f2d540ec9b8]
/home/cubo/anaconda2/bin/../lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalCodeEx+0x7e9)[0x7f2d540ef4e9]
/home/cubo/anaconda2/bin/../lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x6a08)[0x7f2d540ec9b8]
/home/cubo/anaconda2/bin/../lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalCodeEx+0x7e9)[0x7f2d540ef4e9]
/home/cubo/anaconda2/bin/../lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalCode+0x1a)[0x7f2d540ef70a]
/home/cubo/anaconda2/bin/../lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(+0xfd9cd)[0x7f2d541089cd]
/home/cubo/anaconda2/bin/../lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyRun_InteractiveOneFlags+0x15e)[0x7f2d5410aa0e]
/home/cubo/anaconda2/bin/../lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyRun_InteractiveLoopFlags+0x5f)[0x7f2d5410abaf]
/home/cubo/anaconda2/bin/../lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyRun_AnyFileExFlags+0x40)[0x7f2d5410b1f0]
/home/cubo/anaconda2/bin/../lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(Py_Main+0xbac)[0x7f2d5411cf8c]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf0)[0x7f2d53334830]
python(+0x8bf)[0x557e9968a8bf]
```

I'm working on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: If you would, please add the code that is causing this error.  Have you verified this is a valid netCDF?

Comment: It is a valid netCDF. iI'm just usin:
>>import xarray as xr
>>xr.open('period1_7-74_mascara-landsat_7_-74_(2014-01-012014-12-31)_output.nc', engine='netcdf4')

Comment: Can you try opening your dataset directly with `netcdf4.Dataset()`? I would verify that you can do some basic things like `ncdump -h` and `ncview` on the file as well.

Comment: I can open it with netcdf4.Dataset(), also I can check the variable with ncinfo. However I need to open it with xarray to perform some operations

Comment: One thing, please change `xr.open(` to `xr.open_dataset(`.  The current code won't copy and paste into someone's workspace correctly.  Are you using anaconda's python 2.7?  I used your edited code to  open a netCDF file to display a file's dimensions, data variables, and attributes.  I assume this is what you are trying to do.  My known environmental differences are python 3.7 and a different netCDF file.

Comment: Using python 2.7, I can't easily open the same netCDF file.  I am getting a different error than you though, a ValueError.  Are you required to use python 2.7?  Have you tried using an upgraded python?